# setText method and array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, getter-setter

Hi I have this array of a costum class I made called entry but everytime I try to set the text of one of the entry on the array I get an error

```
Entry [] myEntries = new Entry[length];      

for(int i = 0; i < myEntries.length; i++)
{
  myEntries[i].setText(new String(""));
}
```

This my Entry class

```
public class Entry
{
  int date;
  String text;

  Entry(int date)
  {
    this.date = date;
  }

  public void setText(String text) 
  {
    this.text = text;
  } 

  public String getText()
  {
    return text;
  }

  public int getDate() 
  {
    return date;
  }

}
```

Comment: What error that you got ?

Comment: Entry is not of primitive type so it will get initialized with null values and without setting up the values you are trying to do some operation on the null value, so you will get an exception i.e. null pointer exception

Answer (score 3):

You will get **`NULL POINTER EXCEPTION`**. Because you need to initialize each and every element in iteration before using each element.  Do as following

```
for(int i = 0; i < myEntries.length; i++)
{
 myEntries[i] = new Entry(); 
 myEntries[i].setText(new String(""));
}
```

**Along with this you also need to create a default constructor to use the above version or pass a date object to use your own version of constructor**

Answer (score 0):

You should assign Entry object to each array element, otherwise you will get `NullPointerException`.

```
Integer[] myEntries = new Integer[5];

// System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myEntries));
// above commented code prints "[null, null, null, null, null]"

for(int i = 0; i < myEntries.length; i++) {
    myEntries[i] = new Entry();
    myEntries[i].setText(new String(""));
}
```

Note: For this to work, you will need a **default** constructor in `Entry` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EntryMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Entry [] myEntries = new Entry[10];      

        for(int i = 0; i < myEntries.length; i++)
        {
            try {
                myEntries[i].setText(new String(""));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                myEntries[i] = new Entry();
                myEntries[i].setText(new String(""));
            }

        }  
    }
}
```

Entry.java

```
public class Entry
{

  Entry() 
  {

  }

  int date;
  String text;

  Entry(int date)
  {
    this.date = date;
  }

  public void setText(String text) 
  {
    this.text = text;
  } 

  public String getText()
  {
    return text;
  }

  public int getDate() 
  {
    return date;
  }

}
```

since myEntries[] is empty and you are trying to read some index it will give you null pointer exception.

As above many people mentioned if you directly assign a new Entry() it will override the previous object and you will loose data.

so, try to access a position in myEntries[] if exception happens then assign a new Entry() to myEntries[] and setText("whateever")

Answer (score -3):

Try replacing 
new String("") with the variable instead.

If that doesn't help, show the whole code or error you get when you try compile

Comment: Please check the other answers for the actual reason or atleast try your own before suggesting